# swift 3 WKWebView delegate WKNavigationDelegate Ambiguous method

Tags: ios, swift3, wkwebview

I created a class named `JSBridge`, this class implements the `WKNavigationDelegate`, I did some custom stuff in the protocol method, and then call another `UIViewController`'s default `WKNavigationDelegate`, for example `WebViewController` aka `webViewDelegate`, so I have to do like this

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    guard let webViewDelegate = webViewDelegate , self.webView == webView else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        return
    }

    //do something here then call `WebViewController`'s implementation
    if webViewDelegate.responds(to: #selector(webViewDelegate.webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:))) {
            webViewDelegate.webView!(webView, decidePolicyFor: navigationAction, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    guard let webViewDelegate = webViewDelegate , self.webView == webView else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        return
    }

    //do something here then 
    if webViewDelegate.responds(to: #selector(webViewDelegate.webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:))) {
        webViewDelegate.webView!(webView, decidePolicyFor: navigationResponse, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

my problem is in xcode8(swift3) the compiler gives me the error:
     `Ambiguous use of 'webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)'`, they have the same name to compiler

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `as` to choose one from some ambiguous methods:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    guard let webViewDelegate = webViewDelegate , self.webView == webView else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        return
    }

    typealias WKNavigationActionMethodType = (WKWebView,WKNavigationAction,@escaping(WKNavigationActionPolicy)->Void) -> Void
    if webViewDelegate.responds(to: #selector(webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:) as WKNavigationActionMethodType)) {
        webViewDelegate.webView!(webView, decidePolicyFor: navigationAction, decisionHandler: decisionHandler)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

---

Another way to treat this sort of situation is "avoid using `responds(to:)` and use Optional chaining":

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    guard let webViewDelegate = webViewDelegate , self.webView == webView else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        return
    }

    if webViewDelegate.webView?(webView, decidePolicyFor: navigationAction, decisionHandler: decisionHandler) == nil {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

The delegate method's return type is `Void`, so its Optional chained result is of type `Void?`. In your case, it becomes `nil` only when the optional method is not implemented in the instance. So, comparing the result to `nil` is checking the optional method is implemented (and actually called) or not.

Comment: Great approach!